# Dropdown below text field in SuiteCRM

Tags: user-interface, drop-down-menu, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want a dropdown of (Selectable) predictions to appear below while I type in a text field of Tasks module. I know how to change dropdown values of a dropdown field from database values but user can't input new value into the dropdown field(Only can select). I want the user to be able to type entry into text field as usual with clickable suggestions of the entered text below like a dropdown. I am new to SuiteCRM so file paths would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please use select2 javascript plugin for the same.
PFB for example,

```
$("#field_name").select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a data',
    allowClear: true,
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    tags: [],
    ajax: {
        url: '<your url>',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        quietMillis: 1000,
        delay: 900,
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                data:$('#field_name').val(),    
            };
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#ajaxloading_c').css('visibility', 'visible'); 
            $('#ajaxloading_c').css('display', 'block');
            $('#ajaxloading_mask').css('display', 'block'); 
        },
        results: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.name,
                        id: item.id 
                    }
                })
            };
            $('#select2-field_name-results li').first().remove();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#ajaxloading_c').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $('#ajaxloading_c').css('display', 'none');
            $('#ajaxloading_mask').css('display', 'none');  
            $('#select2-field_name-results li').first().remove();
            if($('#select2-field_name-results li:first').text() == 'No data Found'){
                $("#select2-field_name-results li:first").css("pointer-events", "none");
            }
        }
    }
});
$('.select2-container--focus, .select2-container--default').css('width','70%');
```